# Java /Android Dialog with EditText - Boolean check on strings

Tags: java, android, dialog, boolean, android-edittext

I have a boolean method returning true or false to check whether or not data exists inside of strings.  Everything works ok if the user enters all data or does not run through the dialogs.....BUT....if the user DOES NOT enter data in the "getItemsEditText" dialog popup AND still clicks "OK", this boolean is resolving to true, even though "pricePerItemText" still has nothing stored.  This is the boolean method:

```
public Boolean doesAllDataExistCheckBool ()
{

  if (pricePerItemText != "" && itemsPerDayText != "" && sleepTimeText != "" && 
     wakeTimeText != "")
    {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit
       (); //opens shared preference editor
        editor.putBoolean("storedDoesAllDataExist", true);
        editor.commit();  //commit changes to mySharedPreferences
        //End storing shared preferences
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit
        (); //opens shared preference editor
        editor.putBoolean("storedDoesAllDataExist", false);
        editor.commit();  //commit changes to mySharedPreferences
        //End storing shared preferences

        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is where the boolean is being tested to see if true or false:

```
if (position == 4)
  {
    allDataExists = doesAllDataExistCheckBool ();  //checks if true or false

    if (serviceStarted == true)
     {
       Context context = getApplicationContext();
       String text = "Schedule is already running";
       int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
       toast.show();
     }
   if (serviceStarted == false && doesAllDataExistCheckBool () == true)
     {
     startScheduleService();
     }
   if (serviceStarted == false && doesAllDataExistCheckBool () == false)
     {
       Context context = getApplicationContext();
       String text = "Please enter all data before starting!";
       int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
       toast.show();
     }

}
```

Here is how the dialog with EditText and OK/Cancel buttons is written:

```
case ITEMS_PER_DAY :

LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);

final View itemsEntryView = li.inflate(R.layout.settings_dialog_input, (ViewGroup)
findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

final EditText getItemsEditText = (EditText)itemsEntryView.findViewById
(R.id.DialogEditText);


return new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsActivity.this)

 .setTitle("This is the title")

 .setView(itemsEntryView)

 .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
 {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
  {

    itemsPerDayText = getItemsEditText.getText().toString();  //gets input from 
    edittext and saves it to a string itemsPerDayText


    //Initialize shared preferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit(); //opens editor
   editor.putString("storedItemsPerDayText", itemsPerDayText); 
   editor.commit();  //commit changes to mySharedPreferences
   //End storing shared preferences

   }
 })
 .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
   {
    //user click cancel
   }
}).create();
```

Is there another way to do this?  Why can the user still click "OK" if they did not enter anything at all?  Any ideas?  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted way too much code. But right away I noticed this

```
pricePerItemText != ""
```

Assuming pricePerItemText is a string, which we really have no idea since you didn't include that, that's not how you compare strings in java. It needs to be

```
!pricePerItemText.equals("");
```

*Edit*:

In java, the `==` operator  compares objects references, not values. So

```
String mytext = "text";
if (mytext == "text"){ print "True"}
```

will never print true because the `mytext` variable is pointing to some memory location, which is most definitely not the same as where "text" points to.

The fact that

```
"text == "text"
```

is true is a an artifact of Java keeping a string pool so it doesn't have to reallocate new strings. This is a major cause of confusion.

Here's a random link which describes it probably better

http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html

Comment: Thanks Falmarri.  Sorry about the posting of all that code.  I just wanted to make sure whomever was looking at it could logically run through it all.  I knew it was something dumb.  Yes, you probably know this already.  I'm a Java NOOB.

Comment: @dell116: It's always a trade off between posting too much and too little code. Ideally you should post the smallest bit of compilable code that demonstrates the problem. It's tricky with android though.

Comment: and just to be clear....although I didn't explicitly show in my code that pricePerItemText is a string, I did specify that I was testing strings in my description.

Comment: it worked because the boolean is evaluating correctly now. Like I said, I'm new to Java so my syntax may be a bit off at times, but i've been programming for about 3 years. I'm not sure if you're being a sarcastic thread troll or you genuinly want to know if I understand....in which case....yes...I understand....thank you for your concern.

Comment: #dell116: No, he's asking if you understand why pricePerItemText != "" is true regardless of what the value of pricePerItemText is

Comment: Ok.  I thought he was asking if I knew why the boolean was evaluating correctly after the fix.  Falmarri, I understood your correction to be the propor way of evaluating whether or not a string contains whatever is inside .equals(""), which gives a boolean true or false.  To my best understanding, what I was doing before was just asking if the string was not equal to "", which in this case, is always true because that's what the user was setting it to when clicking OK on an empty EditText.  Am I correct on this?  If not, I would greatly appreaciate further explanation.

Comment: No, I'll edit my answer even though this question is asked every day

Comment: well...geez....that's good to know. Thanks for explaining even though you've beat this horse to a bloody mess already. I'm jumping head-first into android with little knowledge of Java, so most of the android books I've found online don't explain much about the way Java behaves. Once again, thank you.